# jquery mobile select with data-native-menu="false" and php array does not work

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I cannot make it work. An php array with jqm data-native-menu="false" does not show all items, but only the first and last one. If data-native-menu="true" then all items are shown. How can I fix it?

```
<?php
$fooArray = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section id="main" data-role="page">

    <header data-role="header" data-theme="b"><h1></h1></header>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose the day:</label>
            <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-native-menu="false">
            <?php foreach ($fooArray as $value) { echo '<option value=>'.$value.'</option>'; } ?>
            </select>
        </div>                
    </div>

    <footer data-role="footer" data-theme="b"><h1></h1></footer>

</section>
</body>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like particularly valid HTML you're making with your PHP loop. What happens when you change `<option value=>` to either not have a `value` attribute or to give it one? Can you make this JSFiddle (of your code) and make it exhibit the behavior? http://jsfiddle.net/KjdjL/1/

Comment: It does not matter if it is php or js array, the effect is the same. Here you have http://jsfiddle.net/WGCYD/ with data-native-menu="false" and here http://jsfiddle.net/WGCYD/1/ with data-native-menu="true" - The "true" shows content. I do need to have an array because number of options is unknown.

Comment: My suggestion was to fix your HTML to be valid, which is what codaniel suggested a few hours later.

Comment: In that case I misunderstood you, any way thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your foreach loop to this

```
<?php foreach ($fooArray as $value) { echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>'; } ?>
```

Comment: Yes, I could if I knew how, I tried to do that but I do not know how.

Comment: Click on the hollow check (tick mark) sign below the voting arrows on the left side of the answer that you would like to accept.